# Qemu Virtual machine very slow

Tags: debian, qemu

This is my first time using Qemu, and creating my own virtual machine. I feel like a complete newb ;(

Debian Linux host Uname -a:
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u5 (2015-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Debian Linux guest VM uname-a:
linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP debian 3.16.7.ckt11-1+deb8u5 (2015-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I've created a basic Debian Jessie VM. The install took 24hours !

My finished virtual machine works OK, but is painfully slow ! Even typing at the terminal is excruciating.

I was hoping I would be able to share this with my colleagues for a project we are working on. But if it runs this slowly they won't be impressed.

I don't even know where to begin for how to troubleshoot ?

I've read about changing the cache setting, but how do I change this ? Setting file, at start up ?

What about adjusting the VM's memory use, how can I be sure it is using a part of the hosts memory (I don't want it to use all of it, but it can certainly have a couple of gigs).

It is intended to only be a 'testing' zone, so I don't expect to have a heavy load (no game playing etc) but I do want to be able to run a LAMP stack.

One thing which didn't help is that the qemu command is different and even the official docs don't seem to mention that I should have been using qemu-system-x84-64 - thank god for SO !

Thanks in advance for your help, I know it looks like I've not done my research, but unfortunately what I have read has completely baffled me.

David

edit 1:

I created the Vm as follows

Install qemu etc:

sudo apt-get install qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-bin

Created a qcow disk (I realise this is a large disk, but I figured I should try to make things as easy as possible for my future colleages):

qemu-img create -f qcow2 debian.qcow 15G

Start the install of the new system :

qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.qcow -cdrom debian-8.2.0-amd64-CD-1.iso

Comment: You're missing several [necessary](http://serverfault.com/a/729821/126632) and useful command line options. Make things easy on _yourself_ and use `virt-manager`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton OK, what options, and how do I learn about them (first I have read about VTx, do I need it ?). Truth is I just followed the basic instruction on the debian qemu wiki !

Comment: In your comment in the linked question, you mention using a 'non standard linux distro like debian or ubuntu' In what way are they 'non standard' for qemu ?

Comment: Besides the debian qemu wiki entry you refer to, which seems to give bizarre instructions? Too many ways to list here; comments can only be 600 characters, and it would need most of a book to explain everything that's wrong with Debian.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you made me laugh, not bad for 3 in the morning. I guess I've just become 'habituated' to debian over the years. I agree somewhat I guess, but could probably find fault with any OS ;)

Comment: @MichaelHampton, so I've done as you suggested, much easier. if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: did you fix issue create VM with qemu-system-x86_64 take a long times? if you're done, you can guide me fix it, i have issue like you. Thanks.

Comment: @BillHuyAnh, is used Michael Hampton's advice and used Virt-Manager. I'm running a linux system as the host, and this worked much better. Good luck